# Class.forName(Class) in a specific directory?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, jar, directory

While testing a program I am developing that writes to a SQLite database, I noticed that if I moved my sqlite.jar file to a sub-directory, `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` throws the ClassNotFoundException. Is there a way that I can change the directory that `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` is looking in so that I can store the file where I want it?

Comment: ha ha. is it sqlite.jar in build path?

Comment: Class.forName is not looking for a directory, it's looking for a class in your classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the classpath is set to work with that location. If you are using an IDE, add the library to your build path in your project properties and then execute your code. The IDE will do the rest of the things you need to do.

If you are working with classpath setup, you should not move your files from the classpath where the class files are specified and your program will look for its desired class to load.

Comment: Thanks, forgetting to update the location in the project properties was dumb on my part.